# Проблема с кросс-доменным запросом в FireFox

Tags: ajax

Есть проблема: при авторизации на одном ресурсе (напр. a.com) нужно по-тихому (через jQuery-ajax) авторизоваться на другом ресурсе (b.com) - база пользователей обеих ресурсов общая. При этом на страничке авторизации пишется js-код

```
var form = jQuery('#auth_form');
var data = form.serialize();
var url = 'http://www.b.com/auth';
jQuery.ajax({
  url: url,
  crossDomain: true,
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'html',
  data: data,
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  },
  success: function (html) {
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
  }
});
```

Сервер при ответе выставляет все требуемые CORS заголовки

```
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.a.com");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTION");
    header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token");
```

Странность в том, что в Chrome и Opera это работает на-ура, а вот злой FireFox похоже даже не отправляет запрос и в консоль пишет такое:

> Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного
>   источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на http://www.b.com. Это
>   может быть исправлено путем перемещения ресурса в тот же домен или
>   включением CORS.

FireFox последней версии (37.0.1) везде пишется, что версии 3.5+ поддерживают CORS и поэтому что происходит - ва-аще не понимаю. Пробовал мониторить сеть с помощью Fiddler - реально не вижу запроса из-под FireFox-а (из под Chrome вижу - все норм.). Попытки мудрить с настройками FireFox-а (типа установить capability.policy.default.XMLHttpRequest.open = allAccess) результатов не дают. Чего в таких случаях правильные люди делают?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте посмотреть в хроме какие заголовки помимо указанных в Access-Control-Allow-Headers передаются и прописать их в header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:".тут)

Comment: Какой смысл менять заголовки, если браузер не делает запроса на сервер?